# Is EA Sports Active multilingual?

Tags: nintendo-wii, ea-sports-active

I would like to buy the Wii game EA Sports Active but it doesn't have the usual multilingual badge I see in most Wii games.

The box is only in German here in Switzerland, so can I expect the game to be multilingual and also work in English and Spanish? Or do they have German-only releases?

From the web site, the game seems to be in many languages.

If nobody can answer that, did anybody run the game in a different language than the one in the box, no matter which languages they are?

Comment: Have you e-mailed EA customer support?

Comment: I've found no way to contact them, no single email address and every one I've tried bounced back.

Comment: That is very bad on their part.

Comment: I haven't expected anything different from EA. Something else that's funny: http://pupeno.com/blog/please-select-your-language/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a [forum post](http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/236151.page) on the EA forums, the European version of EA Sports Active supports the following languages:

- English
- French
- Italian
- German
- Spanish.

It will use the language your Wii is set to.